# Errror result Array to string conversion in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have a trouble when parsing sum of one of my column in database to view using codeigniter. It returns error:"array to string conversion", can you help me to solve this problem ? Thank You

This is the code :

Model

```
    function get_total_invest(){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM purchase");
    if($query->num_rows()>0) {
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function index(){
    $d['user_session'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $d['total_invest'] = $this->item_model->get_total_invest();
    $this->load->view('dashboard_view', $d);

}
```

View

```
          <div class="col mr-2">
                    <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-primary text-uppercase mb-1">Asset Invest</div>
                     <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">IDR <?php echo $total_invest?></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: the error is pretty obvious, its an array to string conversion, the result is and array of objects and you are trying to echo that array and echo only for strings.

Comment: `$this->item_model->get_total_invest()` returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this solution in model

Model

```
function get_total_invest(){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(price) TotalPrice FROM purchase");
   if($query->num_rows()>0) { return $query->result()[0]->TotalPrice ; }
   else{  return 0; }
 }
```